# Woocommerce Total Weight Unit Label Problem in Invoice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, invoice

[image: Product Image Marked With Weight Unit Label], [image: Invoice Output]

The product weight unit label is 200ml in woocommerce but when I have downloaded delivery note it’s showing 200kg instead of 200ml. How can I solve this issue. I appreciate friendly solution. Plugin used for the invoice is: https://wordpress.org/plugins/print-invoices-packing-slip-labels-for-woocommerce/

Thanks

I am unable to understand what to do.

Comment: Liters are not, of course, a unit of weight, but of volume. Something in the software sees 200ml, doesn't understand ml, and assumes kg. The shipping weight of a liquid product needs to include the container and packaging.  The appropriate solution is to describe your product as a 200ml bottle of liquid, with a shipping weight of 350g (or whatever the total weight should be).

Comment: My view is only to show the exact weight unit label text in the invoice, It doesn't need to count any kg or ml. You can understand the two marked line in the screenshots.

Comment: still waiting for a proper solution in this topic